# Google Calender in List View - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api, sfcalendar

I am trying to create a flutter page where if I add events to the Google calendar it should show the events in the app as well. I am able to connect the calendar and the UI. I am looking on how to change the following view and get in the form of a list.

This is how my Calendar View looks like now
[image]

Following is an example of how I want it to look like
[image]

I want to see only the days the events are listed for and in this format

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Class Schedule'),
    actions: [
      _buildViewDropdownButton(),
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(),
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: getGoogleEventsData(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<GoogleAPI.Event>> snapshot) {
      {
        return SfCalendar(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            view: _calendarView,
            initialDisplayDate: DateTime.now(),
            dataSource: GoogleDataSource(events: snapshot.data),
            monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(
              appointmentDisplayMode:
                  MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment,
            ));
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

}

This is the UI Flutter code I am using. Please help me out on how to do the following task.